# Verifying deploy failed: "SyntaxError: Unexpected" while Mup builds to NGINX?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, meteor, mup

Trying to build a meteor app through mup to the digitalOceans droplet, which runs on Nginx.

During this process, I always stack on deployment verifictation.

**nodejs & node version: v4.8.4**

**npm version: 2.15.11**

Error:

```
x Verifying Deployment: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
    npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js (wd=/bundle/bundle/programs/server)
    => Starting meteor app on port:80

    /bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:82
    const unicodeNormalizePath = (path) => {
                                         ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
        at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

    => Redeploying previous version of the app

    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

    To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=100'

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And here is logs:https://pastebin.com/zs8FG86V

Thank you!

Comment: Node v4.8.4 does not support some of the ES2015 features. Do you have the `ecmascript` meteor package installed?

Comment: @MasterAM yes it is, `ecmascript@0.8.1`. Should i delete it?

Comment: May be related to [this issue](https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up/issues/729)

Comment: @MasterAM I guess [here](https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up/issues/729) is problem with ssl configuration process.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, by changing  docker image, from `'kadirahq/meteord'` to `'abernix/meteord:base'` in mup.js file.